# Is there an alternative to using ProtectKeysWithCertificate?

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, containers, data-protection

My web application is now running on multiple **Unix** containers (pods), so I had to add a centralized place to share the keys between all pods using **AddDataProtection()**,
I'm using **PersistKeysToDbContext()**, but this problem is even worse when saving to a file share,

Without **ProtectKeysWithCertificate()** the keys are unprotected - nobody wants that

```
<!-- Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form. -->
```

If I use a certificate it gets encrypted just fine, but I prefer not to have to depend on another certificate,

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName(dataProtectionSettings.ApplicationName)
    .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionContext>()
    .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(serviceCertificate)
    .UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(serviceCertificate);
```

I wonder why the key is not just AES encrypted using a password (why does it require certificate)

Is there an alternative? or, what would it take to override this process and implement AES encrypt/decrypt based on a password?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0 this document may help